# Webpack resolve extension “Module not found”

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a fairly complicated project with both express and Angular cohabiting.  For purposes of this posting, I am only worried about the express side.

[image]

My server side custom modules are imported like this:

```
import { PayPal } from "@helpers/paypal";
import { Database } from "@models/database";
```

Using an baseUrl and paths in tsconfig.json

```
"baseUrl": ".", 
    "paths": {
      "@helpers/*": [
        "helpers/*"
      ],
      "@models/*": [
        "models/*"
      ]
    }
```

That all works lovely, however webpack doesn't like it at all:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@helpers/paypal'
```

Typescript (tsc) runs just fine, so the issue is within webpack.  There is plenty of documentation suggesting I should add an **alias**, like this to webpack.config:

```
   module.exports = {
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js",
      ".json"
    ],
    alias: {
       "@helpers/*": path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'helpers')),
    },
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    ...etc
```

I have tried a number of combinations for the path, but none seem to work.

**EDIT TO ADD CONTEXT TO FOLDER STRUCTURE IMAGE**

The path of the helpers folder is:
**/server/helpers**

My import statement that is working in typescript is:
**import { PayPal } from "@helpers/paypal";**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack aliases don't use globs but whenever an alias key is matched, that particular match will be replaced with the value you assigned to it. Because `server/helpers` is a directory, it means you only need to create an alias `@helpers` to it and whenever you import something like `@helpers/paypal` it will expand to `/absolute/path/to/server/helpers/paypal`.

```
alias: {
  "@helpers": path.resolve(__dirname, "server", "helpers")
}
```

This is a very common use of aliases and the documentation for [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) explains that.

Excerpt from the table of [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias):

```
| alias:                | import "xyz"       | import "xyz/file.js"          |
|-----------------------|--------------------|-------------------------------|
| { xyz: "/some/dir" }  | /some/dir/index.js | /some/dir/file.js             |
| { xyz$: "/some/dir" } | /some/dir/index.js | /abc/node_modules/xyz/file.js |
| { xyz: "./dir" }      | /abc/dir/index.js  | /abc/dir/file.js              |
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Unfortunately I am still not getting webpack to resolve the module.  I tried several permutations (including the one you provided) and consulted the resolve.alias documentation.

I am sure it is something simple, but I am overlooking it.

Comment: Is your webpack config in the root of your project? [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is the absolute path to the currently executed file (the wepack config). If that wasn't the issue, please post the output of `webpack --display-error-details`.

Comment: Yes, webpack.config is in the root of the project.  Interestingly, the output of webpack --display-error-details is clean.  
So, now that makes me think the error I was seeing when running my server build is related to something else.  
I will mark this answer as correct since you helped me a lot and start a new question.

Comment: @MattKnight did you figure out the issue? I'm seeing the same problem, and like you, my resolve settings seem consistent with the answer, and I see no errors in `--display-error-details`.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov I gave up and decided that I didn't care as much as I had thought about it.  Two years later, I honestly don't really worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is named `payPal` but you are importing `paypal` (capitalization).